# ExtJS application not looking in the correct app folder

Tags: javascript, extjs, model-view-controller, extjs4

In this [tutorial](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/guide/testing), there is code that reads:

```
Ext.require('Ext.app.Application');

var Application = null;

Ext.onReady(function() {
    Application = Ext.create('Ext.app.Application', {
        name: 'AM',

        controllers: [
            'Users'
        ],

        launch: function() {
            //include the tests in the test.html head
            jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new jasmine.TrivialReporter());
            jasmine.getEnv().execute();
        }
    });
});
```

For me, this leads to a 404 when the application is looking for the application code.

```
GET http://localhost:8000/AM/controller/Users.js?_dc=1394340001581 404 (File not found)
```

Why is it using the application name (AM) instead of the 'app' folder like usual? I tried setting the 'appFolder' config directly to no avail as well. It works fine when I create the application normally using

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'AM',

    // automatically create an instance of AM.view.Viewport
    autoCreateViewport: true,

    controllers: [
        'Users'
    ]
});
```

I am serving the application with a simple http server from the root application directory (where the index.html and app.js live) and using extjs 4.2.1.883.

Comment: Because `Ext.application` does more than just spin up an instance. You can even see the source for it, around line 1420 of `Ext-more.js`.

Comment: I hate errors like this, that don't make sense. It should be noted however, that when using the MVC pattern, it is a better approach to not start your app within the Ext.onReady function. I read this in a couple of threads, but couldn't find out why.

Comment: I was able to get the Ext Example resources resolving, I just had to make sure the directory structure from the examples were nested correctly in an existing, running application I am trying to get jasmine into. Haven't been as lucky actually verifying app startup, but the Extjs major version = 4 test works swimmingly.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the **appFolder**  ex:

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'AM',
    appFolder: "Physical path of appfolder",
    autoCreateViewport: true, 
    controllers: [
        'Users'
    ]
});
```

Create the object for above class. You will get the correct path for controllers

Comment: I tried setting the appFolder, but it didn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

this is how to commonly configure the path mapping:

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig({
    enabled: true,
    paths: {
        'AM': 'app'
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

I never found out why it wasn't working for me, but to continue with the tutorial, I just used Ext.application instead and assigned the application to a global var in launch, i.e.:

```
Ext.application({
    requires: ['Ext.container.Viewport'],
    name: 'AM',
    controllers: [
        'Smiles'
    ],
    autoCreateViewport: false,

    launch: function() {
        window.Application = this;
    }
});
```