# Calling ext.js files under /resource/app directory

Tags: spring, extjs, model-view-controller, extjs5

[image]

This is my folder structure for a spring mvc project

[image]
The app.js file is called from the index.jsp file as the above.

[image]

This is app.js file.

[image]

This is application.js file under /resource/app folder.

[image]

To make sure, I also added another resource handler to spring mvc config.!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5RTjr.png)

Somehow it can see the Application.js file under the app folder, but it failed to find any other files below the app folder....

Do you have any idea what the problem is and how I can solve this one?

Answer (score 0):

Never worked with spring, but you could let extjs handle the js files below the app folder by giving the application the relative path to its js-files.

```
Ext.define('EuroScope.Application', {

    ....

    appFolder: 'app'

    ....
});
```

See: [ExtJS application not looking in the correct app folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22278512/extjs-application-not-looking-in-the-correct-app-folder)

Answer (score 0):

After thoughts of couple days, I realized that the view folder isn't just a view folder. It's a subset of MVVM model. So, if I wanna refer a different view, then I need to create a complte MVVM model first........